# How to map varchar(max) column in SCD transform while doing ETL process in SSIS project?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, scd

In Source table `AAT_TECHNICIAN` column has datatype `varchar(max)` and in destination dimension table having  column  TechnicianName with datatype `varchar(max)` then SCD transform done to load from source to destination. After execute package error came. For other transform also same error is coming.

> Error: The "Slowly Changing Dimension input Columns[AAT_TECHNICIANS]" has a long object data type of DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, or DT_IMAGE, which is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, SSIS SCD doesn't support these datatypes. There are probably two options:

1. Use a different methodology to load the target table i.e. don't use the SSIS SCD functionality
2. Copy the source data into a temporary table that has datatypes supported by SSIS SCD and load it from there